# How can I make a copy of an app hosted on Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a website hosted through Azure. The resource group for the website contains SQL server resource (dev), Storage account, App Service Plan, App Service, SQL database (prod).

Is there a way to make a copy of these resources so that I have them on standby should anything go sideways during a deployment?

Comment: Have you looked into deployment slots? That's specifically what that's for.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Thanks! Using it now :)